# Rails Scoping a payroll period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

I've built a Rails app that logs employee time (clockin/clockout) and calculates total hours, allows exports to CSV/PDF, search timecards based on dates, etc.

What I'm really wanting to do is to implement payroll periods via a scope of some sort of a method.

The payroll period begins on a Sunday and ends on a Saturday 14 days later.  What would be the best way to write a scope like this?  Also is it possible to split the weeks into two for the payroll period?

I wrote these scopes but they are flawed:

```
scope :payroll_week_1, -> {
  start = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week - 1.day
  ending = Time.zone.now.end_of_week - 1.day
  where(clock_in: start..ending)
}
scope :payroll_week_2, -> {
  start = Time.zone.now.end_of_week.beginning_of_day
  ending = Time.zone.now.end_of_week.end_of_day + 6.days
  where(clock_in: start..ending)
}
```

These works if you are currently in a payroll period, but once you pass the end of the week, the scopes no longer work because I'm basing my timing off of `Time.zone.now`

Is there any way to actually do this?  Even if I have to set some sort of static scope or value which says April 10 - 23 is payroll period 1, etc etc.  I'm really not sure how to approach this problem and what might work.  So far what I've written works in the current pay period but as time advances the scope drifts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is to create a scope, which can receive a `start_day` as a parameter:

```
scope :payroll_week_starting, -> (start_day) {
  where(clock_in: start_day..(start_day + 1.week))
}
```

Then, in the future you will be able to call your scope with the first day of your pay period:

```
ModelName.payroll_week_starting(Date.parse('31/12/2015'))
```

### UPDATE:

As per your comment, it seems that you're looking for a bit more information from an architectural perspective. It's pretty tough to help you without understanding your database architecture, so I'm just going to go from a high level.

Let's assume you have an `Employee` model and a `Shift` model with the `clock_in` and `clock_out` fields. You may also want a model called `PayPeriod` with the fields `start_date` and `end_date`.

Each `Employee` `has_many :shifts` and each `PayPeriod` `has_many :shifts`

You might add a couple of class methods on `PayPeriod`, so you can find and/or create the `PayPeriod` for any given datetime.

```
def self.for(time)
  find_by("start_date < ? AND end_date > ?", time, time)
end

def self.create_for(time)
  # yday is the number of days into the current year
  period_start_yday = 14 * (time.yday / 14)
  start_date = Date.new(time.year) + period_start_yday.days
  next_year = Date.new(time.year) + 1.year
  create(
    start_date: start_date,
    end_date: [start_date + 14.days, last_day_of_year].min,
  )
end

def self.find_or_create_for(time)
  for(time) || create_for(time)
end
```

The `create_for` logic is pretty complicated, but an example will help you understand:

Say I clocked in today `May 17th, 2016`, the `yday` for today is `138`, if you use [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) (default for ruby) to divide by 14 (the length of your pay periods), you'll get 9. By multiplying that by 14 again, you'll get 126, which is the most recent `yday` divisible by 14. If you add that number of days to the beginning of this year, you'll get the begining of the `PayPeriod`. The end of the `PayPeriod` is 14 days after the `start_date`, but not rolling over to the next year.

What I would then do, is add a `before_save` callback to `Shift` to find or create the corresponding `PayPeriod`

```
before_save :associate_pay_period

def associate_pay_period
  self.pay_period_id = PayPeriod.find_or_create_for(clock_in)
end
```

Then every `PayPeriod` will have a bunch of `Shift`s, and every `Shift` will belong to a `PayPeriod`.

If, for example, you wanted to get all of the shifts for a specific employee during a specific `PayPeriod` (to perhaps sum the hours worked for that `PayPeriod`) add a scope to `Shift`:

```
scope :for, -> (user) { where(user: user) }
```

And call `pay_period.shifts.for(user)`

## UPDATE #2:

One other (much simpler) thought I had (if you don't want to create an actual `PayPeriod` model), would be to just add a method to the model that has `clock_in` (I'm going to refer to it as `Shift`):

```
def pay_period
  clock_in.to_date.mjd / 14
end
```

Which will basically just boil down any clock_in time to an integer that represents a 14 day period. Then you can call

```
Shift.all.group_by { |shift| shift.pay_period }
```

If you need each `pay_period` to be contained within a single calendar year, you can do:

```
def pay_period
  [clock_in.year, clock_in.to_date.yday / 14]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot.  Do you have any idea of how I would setup a payroll period then somehow split up the weeks to calculate overtime?  The overtime calculation part I have solved but the splitting up of the payroll period seems to elude me.  Nonetheless your answer got me a lot closer to where I need to be :)

Comment: This is really good, thanks for taking the time to break it down for me.  I'm not sure this exact architecture will work with my existing app without an overhaul, but I will be using bits of it to work towards a final solution. This is not an easy problem to solve but I appreciate your effort!

Comment: @shakycode I've added one more update that is a much more simple implementation, which will hopefully help you. If you appreciate my efforts, I would appreciate an upvote. If there is anything else I can help you with, let me know.

Comment: Upvoted and thanks for the second implementation advice!